# fuse: pass through custom open flags from the "open(2)" call `.open` handler in fuse implementation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, fuse, libfuse

I have implemented a fuse driver for cache management. I would like to give some hints from the application side to fuse driver using file system calls like `open(2)`, e.g., sequential read pattern.

I thought I could use the `flags` argument in `open(2)`[1](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and thought it would be passed to the fuse handler [2](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/include/fuse.h#L447). I have done some experiments and found the my custom bits are not shown in the fuse's `.open` handler in the `struct fuse_file_info *`.

I would like to know why but I failed to find any documentation about the flags validation/stripping rules in the linux kernel documentation and libuse documentation. Can anyone point me to the specification or related source code?

Besides, I'm wondering if passing custom (not specified in `fcntl.h`) is not possible, is three other approaches where I can pass some hints from the application to the fuse handler?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What are the flags you've tried? because [doc of open](https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#a14b98c3f7ab97cc2ef8f9b1d9dc0709d) says:

`Creation (O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NOCTTY) flags will be filtered out / handled by the kernel.`

As for alternatives, the standard way for any file system, not necessarily fuse, would be a dedicated `ioctl`. In case the hint is per file and not per specific opened descriptor, `setxattr` is also an option.

Comment: I have tried flags that are not defined in `fcntl.h`. `ioctl` looks promising. Will test in my fuse implementation. Thanks!